# MySQL total sum based on previous select by date

Tags: mysql

I have a not-very-normalized MySQL table with the following values:

```
customer_ID | date | score | sale
```

As I am scoring the "purchase experience", I would like to check the total sale value for each customer based on his last score. I do not mind about previous scores, just about last one.

Let's say I have:

```
customer_ID | date      | score | sale  
a           | yesterday | 3     | 10  
a           | today     | 6     | 35  
b           | today     | 10    | 20  
c           | yesterday | 4     | 5
```

The result for customers purchases with score > 5 should be:

```
num of customers | total sale values  
2                | 65
```

Any idea of how to create such query?

Edit:

What I want to know is how much has a customer spent in purchases in total, but just on customers whose last score was bigger than 5.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: Inadequate explanation. Try to improve it!

Comment: when you say `yesterday` is it really a literal string value `yesterday`?

Comment: Hi, not yesterday literally. I wrote that to make it easier to understand.
What I want to know is how much has a customer spent in purchases in total, but just on customers whose last score was bigger than 5.

Comment: one more thing for example `customer a` has a record dated 2 days before with a score of 6 and sale of 15, what will be the result? and how was total sale values calculated?

Comment: In this case customer a's rate of 6 is also disregarded, as we have a score from today. However, sale is taken in consideration.

Therefore, the total sale values would be 10+35+15 (customer a) + 20 (customer b) = 80.
So the final result would be

num of customers | total sale values
2                | 80

Comment: @fedorqui wait, i'm confused. where is `15` coming from? see my anser below if it helps. i'll update soon..

Comment: Yes! `15` was coming from your previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT aa.customer_ID) `num of customers`,
        SUM(aa.sale) `total sale values `
FROM    table1 aa
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  a.customer_ID
            FROM    table1  a
                    INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  customer_ID, max(date) max_date
                        FROM    table1
                        GROUP   BY customer_ID
                    ) b ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID AND
                            a.date = b.max_date AND a.score > 5
        ) final ON aa.customer_ID = final.customer_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/052fac/6)

much more simplified,

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT c.customer_ID) `num of customers`,
        SUM(c.sale) `total sale values `
FROM    table1  a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  customer_ID, max(date) max_date
            FROM    table1
            GROUP   BY customer_ID
        ) b ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID AND
                a.date = b.max_date AND a.score > 5
        INNER JOIN table1 c
            ON a.customer_ID = c.customer_ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/052fac/7)